# What is the first word in this baptism record?

Tags: england, palaeography, 17th-century, baptism-records

[image]

My transcript from Bishop's Transcripts, Church of England, Parish of Melbourne, Cambridgeshire. 1616 https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-C9T9-6BN5?i=41&cat=1109075

> J***rimis Thomas Sonne of John Casbold and Joan baptized the 28th of
>   Aprill

I've seen this term on a few other records...does it have a special meaning?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Would you be able to provide a source for that record so that we can see the year (1616?) and parish/county in which it wa made, please?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. Bishop's Transcripts, Church of England, Parish of Melbourne, Cambridgeshire. 1616 https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-C9T9-6BN5?i=41&cat=1109075

Answer (score 11):

*[**Imprimis**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imprimis)* is Latin for "firstly". The word commonly appears in lists in parish registers and wills, preceding the first item.

Comment: Thank you so much! So basically it is just referring to the first record in a given set (the first baptism of the year in this case).